# Execute Procedure in SSIS OLEDB Source

Tags: sql, ssis

`OLEDB` Source Data Access Mode is SQL Command Text

```
EXEC [Baseline_CalculateBaselineDataTestTest]
```

When i preview no of columns and there data is shown, but below error is prompt.

**Error**

Error at Data Flow Task [OLE DB Source [1]]: No column information was returned by the SQL command.

Answer (score 0):

```
    SET FMTONLY OFF
EXEC dbo.GetSourceData
```

[No column information was returned by the SQL command](http://www.sqldbpros.com/2011/12/ssis-no-column-information-was-returned-by-the-sql-command/)

Unfortunately, if the stored procedure is using a temp table (#table) you'll likely encounter the warning "No column information was returned by the SQL command".  Essentially, because of the temporary table SSIS can't determine what columns will be returned by the proc and thus won't let you map them to a destination.